How to conveniently use fzf to find and kill processes from CMD?
I've installed fzf using Chocolatey on my Windows machine. How can I use fzf to find and kill processes from inside the Command Prompt (CMD)?
I'm looking for a streamlined way, similar to how kill -9 **Tab work on POSIX compatible terminals, to search for processes and then terminate them efficiently. I have tried taskkill /IM **Tab to no avail.

fzf integrates with bunch of shells thanks to completion/keybinding scripts it offers for them. cmd.exe is a primitive shell by default, it doesn't offer any good integration possibilities.
To get experience similar to that on Linux shells, you have to:

install clink that modernizes cmd.exe and allows for example LUA scripting
install clink-fzf LUA by downloading .zip of the source code, unpacking it to a folder and then running:

clink installscripts [path to unpacked dir]

Hint: the folder is recommended to be an easily accessible folder so that you can upgrade/uninstall the script quickly. You could also set it up as a repository to fetch directly from git.

configure the LUA by either executing clink set fzf.default_bindings true to set default bindings, including the ** Tab completion you mentioned or by manually assigning the following command to a key in .inputrc: luafunc:fzf_tab.
restart the shell

You might also want to install clink-completions LUAs in a similar way to have better completion capabilities in the 1st place - not entirely sure if taskkill is supported at all.

I downloaded the fzf.lua as instructed on the GitHub repo. and copied to the C:\Users\FoadS\AppData\Local\clink directory. Am I moving in the right direction? What should I do next?

Not really, although that should also work. The installscripts installation method I mentioned is way better and enables much easier upgrading or disabling of scripts if you store them in a more accessible and separate locations.

OK, I deleted the fzf.lua file. downloaded the repos as zip files. ran clink installscripts "path\to\clink-fzf-main" and clink installscripts "path\to\clink-completions-master". and then clink set fzf.default_bindings true. but then taskkill /IM ** Tab shows the files in the current directory.

As I mentioned, not all commands are supported. You'll need to request process completion in the completions repo or code a LUA yourself if it lists files.

should I request on the clink-fzf repo or the clink-completions?

clink-completions. clink-fzf just integrates with available completions.

OK then. And I think I should not delete the folders that I ran clink installscripts <path> for, right? Or are they copied somewhere else and it is OK to remove them?

No, they should stay. You upgrade the scripts there like I mentioned

then could you be kind to add this to your answer, so people think it through in advance and do not place the folders in an ugly place like I did in my Download folder?
